# Opacity is not working when position:absolute in IE10

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-10

Opacity is not working when position is absolute

```
a.Button5{
  display:block; 
  opacity:0.7;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
 }
a.Button5:hover{
  opacity:1;
}


<a href="(imageFile)" class="button5" rel="lightbox[imgBox]">
            <div class="ch-item cha_01">
                    <div class="ch-info" style="top:0px; left:30px;">
                    <h3>(Text)</h3>
                    </div>
        </div>
</a>



.cha_12{
position:relative;
float:left;
width:225px;
height:160px; 
top:0px;
left:0px;
background-image:url(images/cha_ra_04.png); }
```

this works very well.
but

```
.cha_12{position:absolute;
float:left;
width:136px;
height:378px; 
top:316px;
left:814px;
background-image:url(images/cha_ra_12.png);}
```

this doesn't work in IE10.(Firefox, chrome is working very well)
I don't know what i do wrong. please help me

Comment: Is your document in strict or quirks mode? You can tell specifically by running `document.compatMode` in JS, but a more obvious thing to look for is what if any doctype you’ve specified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

be more specific

```
a .ch-item {
    opacity:0.7;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}
a:hover .ch-item {
    opacity:1;
}
```